# Python Script Infinite Loop untill specific Keypress

Tags: python, loops

I am a total newbie at coding but I made a simple script:

```
import time
import keyboard

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('F3'):
            time.sleep(1)
            keyboard.press('enter')
            continue
    except:
        break
```

When I press F3, the script makes the computer press the Enter key. The problem is it only does it once until you press F3 again.

How can I make it go forever until I press F3 to stop it?

Comment: Why the try-except? Bare except statements are a bad idea, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that I understand the question correctly. In order to stop pressing enter when F3 is pressed you should move these lines:

```
time.sleep(1)
keyboard.press('enter')
```

outside of the `if`-statement. Like this:

```
import time
import keyboard

while True:
    try:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('F3'):
            break
        time.sleep(1)
        keyboard.press('enter')
    except:
        break
```

Also, the `continue` is not needed here. And because the program sleeps for 1 second after checking for the keypress, you will have to hold the F3-key for at least 1 second.

To start the loop by pressing a key, you could start the function with the following:

```
while not keyboard.is_pressed('F3'):
    pass

time.sleep(0.1)
```

Now the function will wait until the F3-key is pressed. The small delay is needed because otherwise the keyboard function will think the F3-key is pressed when it enters the second loop. I found that a 100 ms delay works fine.

If you choose another key then the F3-key, this delay will not be needed.

Comment: Thank you but how can i make the keyboard.press('enter') loop after another key was pressed ? I dont want the script running untill after a certain key for example

Comment: @Equinox I added the functionality to check whether a key is pressed (the F3 key) before starting the loop

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code so it starts with the F3 and stops with the F4 keys. Here it is for anyone reading !

```
import time
import keyboard
from random import randint


def main():
    x = 0
    while x == 0:
        try:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('F3'):
                x = 1
        except:
            x = 0
    while x == 1:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('F4'):
            break
        try:
            time.sleep(randint(2,3))
            keyboard.press('enter')
        except:
            break

main()
```